# Resources exceeded BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When running the following query I got the error:

Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 158% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 98% other/unattributed: 2%

```
select *, row_number() over(PARTITION BY Column_A ORDER BY Column_B)
from
(SELECT
*
FROM
  Table_1 UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table_2 UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table_3
)
```

Can someone help me how to change this query or is there possibility that we can change the memory limit in bigquery?

Answer (score 9):

Welcome Aaron,

This error means BigQuery is unable to process the whole query due to memory limits, the `ORDER BY` function is pretty memory intensive, try removing it and I would expect your query to run fine.

If you need results ordered, try writing the unordered query out to a table then running a new query on this table to order the results.

If you're interested. here's an interesting article on how and BigQuery executes in memory:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/in-memory-query-execution-in-google-bigquery

I don't believe you can override or change this memory limit, but happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: I know this isa bit old, but does `OVER (PARTITION BY ...` has the same effect?

Comment: @IslamAzab it depends on how big your partitions are. If you have one partition with everything, it would be just as bad. If you `PARTITION BY` a unique key, the sorting only needs to sort one value at a time.

For the query I am working on right now, the `ORDER BY` was a problem but the `WINDOW` operations worked once I removed the full results sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `ORDER BY` is being executed in real last step, additionally, consider to use a `LIMIT` clause to avoid “*Resources Exceeded*” or “*Response too large*” fails.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this before and turns out I was trying to partition by a column with "NULL" values. Removing the NULL records worked!

Comment: Also, I've found that clustering the table by the columns you need to ORDER BY in your window function drastically improves performance!

Answer (score 0):

My primary recommendation here is to make sure to use partitioning and clustering.

Partitions apply to date field so if your Table_1, Table_2... has one, partition on it.

Clustering also greatly helps the memory cost of OVER clauses with ORDER BY because it sorts storage blocks ([BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables))

To make the most of both of the above, I would also replace your UNION ALL sub-query with a temporary table.
Storing the result of the UNION ALL to memory, doing the partitioning+clustering of the resulting dataset and only then computing the rank is **much** more efficient in terms of memory and storage ([Medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/bigquery-sql-optimization-2-with-temp-tables-to-fast-results-41869b15fcff))

Your final statement should look something like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp
PARTITION BY date
CLUSTER BY column_A, column_B
AS
SELECT
*
FROM
  Table_1 UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table_2 UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table_3
;

select *, row_number() over(PARTITION BY Column_A ORDER BY Column_B) from tmp
```

Answer (score -4):

You can try OVER without using ORDER BY